# Slowest decay for Fourier transform of test functions.

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ denote the space of test functions(i.e. smooth and with compact support). Suppose $f\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, let's consider decay of its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$. Of course $\hat{f}$ in [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space). So $|\hat{f}(t)|=O(|t|^{-N})$ for each positive integer $N$.

> Is this Optimal when we take all test functions into our consideration?

Something related: In [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179182/a-example-on-fourier-tranform-of-a-continous-compactly-supported-function), Joonas Ilmavirta proved for test functions, $\hat{f}$ can't have $e^{-k|x|^\gamma}$ decay rate, if $\gamma >1$. And the Standard [Bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) $\Phi$, [such that](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.04376.pdf) $|\hat{\Phi}(x)|=O(x^{-\frac{3}{4}}e^{-\sqrt{|x|}})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi = e^{-1/(1-x^2)}1_{|x|< 1}$. Its Fourier transform is real and even.

For any $\hat{g}\ge 0$ continuous even decreasing on $[0,\infty)$ and such that $\forall n, \hat{g}=o(t^{-n})$

Then $$\hat{f}=\hat{g} \ast \hat{\phi}^2$$ doesn't decay faster than $\hat{g}$.

And its inverse Fourier transform $$f=g \cdot (\phi \ast \phi)$$ is $C^\infty_c$, since $g$ is $C^\infty$ and $\phi \ast \phi$ is $C^\infty_c$.